# Arrays product in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dot-product

I have defined couple of arrays in Python but I am having problem in calculation of the product.

```
import numpy as np
phi = np.array([[ 1.,  1.],[ 0.,  1.]])
P = np.array([[ 999.,    0.],[   0.,  999.]])
np.dot(phi, P, phi.T)
```

I get the error:
ValueError: output array is not acceptable (must have the right type, nr dimensions, and be a C-Array)

But I do not know what is the problem, since the size of matrix or array is 2 by 2

Comment: Have you tried the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)?

Comment: Yes, and I still have problem.

Comment: Your question is at -1 (a the time being). Did you try to multiply three matrices or you tried to save the output on transposed matrix?

Answer (score 4):

As the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) explains, `numpy.dot` only multiplies two matrices. The third, optional argument is an array in which to store the results. If you want to multiply three matrices, you will need to call `dot` twice:

```
numpy.dot(numpy.dot(phi, P), phi.T)
```

Note that arrays have a `dot` method that does the same thing as `numpy.dot`, which can make things easier to read:

```
phi.dot(P).dot(phi.T)
```

Answer (score 1):

`phi.T` is the same as `phi.transpose()` (as stated in the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy.ndarray.T)). It is basically a return value of a class method. Therefore you can't use it as an output storage for the `dot` product.

**Update**
It appears that there is an additional problem here, that can be seen if saving the transposed matrix into  new variable and using it as an output:

```
>>> g = phi.T
>>> np.dot(phi, P, g)
```

is still giving an error. The problem seem to be with the way the result of `transpose` is stored in the memory. The output parameter for the `dot` product has to be C-contiguous array, but in this case `g` is not like that. To overcome this issue the `numpy.ascontiguousarray` method can be used, which solves the problem:

```
>>> g = np.ascontiguousarray(phi.T)
>>> np.dot(phi, P, g)
array([[ 999.,  999.],
       [   0.,  999.]])
```

Comment: I stored the transpose matrix in another variable like g and after that I executed np.dot(phi, P, g) but I am still getting error. So I guess thats not the problem.

Comment: I am sure, its not about transpose matrix. Try this: a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])    b=np.array([[1,1],[1,0]])    c=np.array([[1.5,5],[4,1]])   and later try np.dot(a,b,c).  You will get that error again.

Answer (score 1):

The error message points that there can be 3 reasons why it cannot perform `np.dot(phi, P, out=phi.T)`:

1. "must have the right type": That is ok in the first example, since all the elements of P and phi are floating numbers. But not with the other example mentioned at the comments, where the c[0,0] element is floating point number, but the output array wants to be an integer at all positions since both 'a' and 'b' contains integers everywhere.
2. "nr dimensions":2x2 is the expected dimension of the output array, so the problem is definitely not with the dimensions.
3. "must be a C-Array": This actually means that the output array must be C-contingous. There is a very good description what actually C and F contingous mean: [difference between C and F contingous arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998223/what-is-the-difference-between-contiguous-and-non-contiguous-arrays). To make the long story short, if phi is C-contingous (and by default it is) than phi.T will be F-contingous.

You can check it by checking the flag attributes:

```
    >>> phi.flags
    C_CONTIGUOUS : True
    F_CONTIGUOUS : False
    OWNDATA : True
    ...

    >>> phi.T.flags
    C_CONTIGUOUS : False
    F_CONTIGUOUS : True
    OWNDATA : False
    ...
```