# numpy array size vs. speed of concatenation

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am concatenating data to a numpy array like this:

```
xdata_test = np.concatenate((xdata_test,additional_X))
```

This is done a thousand times. The arrays have dtype `float32`, and their sizes are shown below:

```
xdata_test.shape   :  (x1,40,24,24)        (x1 : [500~10500])   
additional_X.shape :  (x2,40,24,24)        (x2 : [0 ~ 500])
```

The problem is that when `x1` is larger than ~2000-3000, the concatenation takes a lot longer.

The graph below plots the concatenation time versus the size of the `x2` dimension:

[image: x2 vs time consumption]

Is this a memory issue or a basic characteristic of numpy?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand numpy, all the `stack` and `concatenate` functions are not extremely efficient. And for good reasons, because numpy tries to keep array memory contiguous for efficiency (see [this link about contiguous arrays in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998223/what-is-the-difference-between-contiguous-and-non-contiguous-arrays))

That means that every concatenate operation have to copy the whole data every time. When I need to concatenate a bunch of elements together I tend to do this :

```
l = []
for additional_X in ...:
    l.append(addiional_X)
xdata_test = np.concatenate(l)
```

That way, the costly operation of moving the whole data is only done once.

NB : would be interested in the speed improvement that gives you.

Comment: Yes, one concatenation operation for the whole list is much better than repeated binary ones.  `concatenate` creates an empty result array of the right size, and then copies the data from each of the sources.  The one-time concatenation results in fewer copies.

Answer (score 5):

If you have in advance the arrays you want to concatenate, I would suggest creating a new array with the total shape and fill it with the small arrays rather than concatenating, as every concatenation operation needs to copy the whole data to a new contiguous space of memory.

- First, calculate the total size of the first axis:

  ```
  max_x = 0
  for arr in list_of_arrays:
      max_x += arr.shape[0]
  ```
- Second, create the end container:

  ```
  final_data = np.empty((max_x,) + xdata_test.shape[1:], dtype=xdata_test.dtype)
  ```

  which is equivalent to `(max_x, 40, 24, 24)` but dynamically typed.
- Last, fill the numpy array:

  ```
  curr_x = 0
  for arr in list_of_arrays:
      final_data[curr_x:curr_x+arr.shape[0]] = arr
      curr_x += arr.shape[0]
  ```

The loop above, copies each of the arrays to a previously defined column/rows of the larger array.

By doing this, each of the `N` arrays will be copied to the exact final destination, rather than creating temporal arrays for each of the concatenation.