# a.transpose().ravel()[0]=x cannot change value of original array in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-copy

environment: Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (64-bit), numpy version: 1.11.3
Example:

```
In[1]: import numpy as np
In[2]: a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
In[3]: a
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In[5]: a.transpose()[0] = -1
In[6]: a
Out[6]: 
array([[-1,  2,  3],
       [-1,  5,  6]])
In[7]: a.ravel()[0] = -2 
In[8]: a
Out[8]: 
array([[-2,  2,  3],
       [-1,  5,  6]])
In[9]: a.transpose().ravel()[0] = -3
In[10]: a
Out[10]: 
array([[-2,  2,  3],
       [-1,  5,  6]])
```

I know `transpose()` and `ravel()` return a view of array, so we can change its value of original array. However, when we use `transpose().ravel()`, we cannot change it? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `ravel` is returning a copy, not a view

From the [`numpy.ravel` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy-ravel):

> A 1-D array, containing the elements of the input, is returned. A copy is made only if needed.

So basically, when ravelling the transpose, a copy is in fact needed. You're changing the value in a copy, so that's not reflected in the original array.

## Testing whether a returned array is a view or a copy

For a simple case like this, you can test whether an array `b` is or is not a view of `a` by comparing the identity of `b.base` and `a`:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
b = a.T
c = b.ravel()

print('b is a view of a\n%s\n' % (b.base is a))
print('c is a view of a\n%s\n' % (c.base is a))
```

Output:

```
b is a view of a
True

c is a view of a
False
```

## Why does `a.T.ravel()` return a copy?

Shocker: there actually is a way to make `a.T.ravel()` return a view instead of a copy. You can do so by explicitly setting `order='F'` (ie Fortran order):

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
c = a.T.ravel()
d = a.T.ravel(order='F')

print('d is a view of a\n%s\n' % (d.base is a))
```

Output:

```
d is a view of a
True
```

However, changing the value of the `order` kwarg will change the order (fancy that) of the values in the raveled array:

```
print('c\n%s\n' % c)
print('d\n%s\n' % d)
```

Output:

```
c
[1 4 2 5 3 6]

d
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

In order to understand why a change in the `order` leads to a view being returned, we can look at the code of the `ravel` function itself. The implementation of `np.ndarray.ravel` is [buried in the C layer](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/shape.c#L878). Reading over the source for that, it's clear that in order to return a view from `ravel`, two conditions must be met:

- The input array must be contiguous.
- The order of the contiguous input array must match that of the `order` kwarg passed into `ravel`.

The kwarg has a default value of `order='C'`. Thus, by default `ravel` will only return a view if you run it on a C-contiguous array. Most of the time when you initialize a fresh Numpy array `a`, it will start off as C-contiguous. However, the transpose `a.T` will be F-contiguous. You can see this in action in your code by checking the [`.flags` property](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html#numpy-ndarray-flags) of your arrays:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

print('the flags of a\n%s\n' % a.flags)
print('the flags of a.T\n%s\n' % a.T.flags)
```

Output:

```
the flags of a
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

the flags of a.T
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

## What the heck do C- and F-contiguous mean?

There's a good chance that the terms C-contiguous and F-contiguous seem like gibberish to you. Explaining them would require a whole other question, which happily someone on SO has already asked. Here's [a link to an old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26999092/425458) that gives a really intuitive overview of what C and F order actually mean.

## Caveat

In your actual code, I wouldn't worry too much about whether `ravel` is return views or copies. In reality, you don't always get a performance boost by ensuring the use of views. Avoid premature optimization in general.

Comment: why ravelling the transpose, a copy is in fact needed?

Comment: Okay, I've added all of the details about why `ravel` is returning a copy instead of a view. Sadly, it's a little complicated (and about 3 times as long as my original answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
In [382]: a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
In [383]: a
Out[383]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [384]: a.ravel()
Out[384]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

`ravel` gives a 1d view of the array - and shows the values in the order that they occur in the data buffer.

```
In [385]: a.T
Out[385]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
In [386]: a.T.ravel()
Out[386]: array([1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6])
```

`ravel` of the transpose shows elements in a different order - unless we specify the order as 'F' (or 'K').

```
In [387]: a.T.ravel(order='F')
Out[387]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

`ravel` (and other operations) makes a `view` if the array can use the original data, with only a change in `shape` and `strides`.  If it can't, it has to make a copy.

Because of this change in element order with transpose, indexing with something other than `[0]`, selects a different value:

```
In [397]: a.ravel()[3]
Out[397]: 4               # -1 in your Out[8]
In [398]: a.T.ravel()[3]
Out[398]: 5
```

You see there's a certain ambiguity when you ask to change the 4th element of the transpose.  It can differ depending on how you traverse the elements.