# How to use argmax to return indices into multidimensional ndarray that cannot be re-shaped into a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, argmax

Given an array of 2, 9x9 images with 2 channels shaped like this:

```
img1 = img1 = np.arange(162).reshape(9,9,2).copy()
img2 = img1 * 2
batch = np.array([img1, img2])
```

I need to slice each image into 3x3x2 (stride=3) regions and then locate and replace max elements of each slice. For the example above these elements are:

- `(:, 2, 2, :)`
- `(:, 2, 5, :)`
- `(:, 2, 8, :)`
- `(:, 5, 2, :)`
- `(:, 5, 5, :)`
- `(:, 5, 8, :)`
- `(:, 8, 2, :)`
- `(:, 8, 5, :)`
- `(:, 8, 8, :)`

So far my solution is this:

```
batch_size, _, _, channels = batch.shape
region_size = 3

# For the (0, 0) region
region_slice = (slice(batch_size), slice(region_size), slice(region_size), slice(channels))
region = batch[region_slice]
new_values = np.arange(batch_size * channels)

# Flatten each channel of an image
region_3d = region.reshape(batch_size, region_size ** 2, channels)

region_3d_argmax = region_3d.argmax(axis=1)
region_argmax = (
    np.repeat(np.arange(batch_size), channels),
    *np.unravel_index(region_3d_argmax.ravel(), (region_size, region_size)),
    np.tile(np.arange(channels), batch_size)
)

# Find indices of max element for each channel
region_3d_argmax = region_3d.argmax(axis=1)

# Manually unravel indices
region_argmax = (
    np.repeat(np.arange(batch_size), channels),
    *np.unravel_index(region_3d_argmax.ravel(), (region_size, region_size)),
    np.tile(np.arange(channels), batch_size)
)

batch[region_slice][region_argmax] = new_values
```

There are two problems with this code:

- Reshaping `region` may return a copy instead of view
- Manual unraveling

What is the better way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### With merging axes

The better way (on memory and hence performance efficiency) is to use `advanced-indexing` to create the appropriate indexing tuple -

```
m,n = idx.shape
indexer = np.arange(m)[:,None],idx,np.arange(n)
batch_3d[indexer].flat = ...# perform replacement with 1D array
```

The last step could be written differently by reshaping the replacement-array to the indexed shape (if not already so, otherwise skip) -

```
batch_3d[indexer] = replacement_array.reshape(m,n)
```

We can also use the built-in [`np.put_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html) with `p` as the replacement array -

```
np.put_along_axis(batch_3d,idx[:,None,:],p.reshape(m,1,n),axis=1)
```

Note: The `idx` used in this post is the one generated from : `idx = batch_3d.argmax(axis=1)`, hence we are skipping the `manually unravel indices` step.

---

#### Without merging axes

We would define helper funcs to achieve our argmax based replacements along multiple axes without merging axes that are not adjacent, as they will force copy.

```
def indexer_skip_one_axis(a, axis):
    return tuple(slice(None) if i!=axis else None for i in range(a.ndim))

def argmax_along_axes(a, axis):
    # a is input array
    # axis is tuple of axes along which argmax indices are to be computed
    argmax1 = (a.argmax(axis[0]))[indexer_skip_one_axis(a,axis[0])]
    val_argmax1 = np.take_along_axis(a,argmax1,axis=axis[0])
    argmax2 = (val_argmax1.argmax(axis[1]))[indexer_skip_one_axis(a,axis[1])]
    val_argmax2 = np.take_along_axis(argmax1,argmax2,axis=axis[1])
    r = list(np.ix_(*[np.arange(i) for i in a.shape]))
    r[axis[0]] = val_argmax2
    r[axis[1]] = argmax2
    return tuple(r)
```

Hence, to solve our case to do all the replacements would be -

```
m,n,r,s = batch.shape
batch6D = batch.reshape(m,n//3,3,r//3,3,s)
batch6D[argmax_along_axes(batch6D, axis=(2,4))] = new_values.reshape(2,1,1,1,1,2)
out = batch6D.reshape(m,n,r,s)
```

Comment: I have updated the Q with the shape of the new_values array. Please elaborate on your code samples. The intention of some lines is not clear to me...

Comment: @Kentzo Just use the last two suggested solutions.

Comment: @Kentzo Did that make sense?

Comment: I need to mediate over the meaning of put_along_axis's arguments :)

Comment: Is there a way to avoid `batch_3d`? It looks like that depending on the shape `reshape` may return a copy and modification of `batch_3d` won't be reflected in `batch`.

Comment: @Kentzo Nope, `reshape` won't return a copy. How did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: @Kentzo .. given `batch` is a contiguous array - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998223/what-is-the-difference-between-contiguous-and-non-contiguous-arrays, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html

Comment: I realized that my example did not demonstrate the complete case. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Thanks. Also updated the Q with changed I made in the meanwhile.