# expand and copy 1D numpy array to 3D

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1D array that I need to be expanded to 3D, with the original array copied across `axis=0`.

Currently, I have a setup like this:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
y = np.zeros((len(x), 5, 5))

for i in range(5):
  for j in range(5):
    y[:, i, j] = x

print(y)

[[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
  [2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
  [2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
  [2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
  [2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]]

 [[3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
  [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
  [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
  [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
  [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]]

 [[4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
  [4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
  [4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
  [4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
  [4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]]

 [[5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
  [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
  [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
  [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
  [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]]]
```

It strikes me that there should be an easier way to do this than with nested `for` loops, but anything that shows up with a cursory search shows how to cut up a long 1D array and make it 3D, but not copying the initial dimension into 2 more dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of options. You can do it with [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) like this:

```
y = np.tile(x[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis], (1, 5, 5))
```

This will give you a new [contiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26998223) array with the contents you want. However, if you do not need to write into the resulting array, you can use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) to make a read-only view of the array with the new shape, saving you the memory of actually creating the bigger array:

```
y = np.broadcast_to(x[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis], (5, 5, 5))
```

Note that, since this is a view, in this case changing a value in `x` would change the values in `y`.