# NumPy get indices per column of the entries which are equal to max value per column in a 2D-array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an 2D-array:

```
A = np.array([[2,3,4],
              [2,0,4],
              [1,3,7]])
```

I am searching for the **indices per column**, which respresent the maximum value of this column **without using a for loop**.

What I would like to have, is something like:

```
max_rowIndices_perColumn = np.array([[0,1],[0,2],[2]])
```

I had the idea to use:

```
np.where(A== np.amax(A,axis=0))
```

but as in the second step, I would like to work with every specific column itself, I am not really happy with this idea.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some deeper knowledge about behaviour of indexing.

Basically, `np.where` returns advanced indices of True cells in C order (row by row):

```
>>> np.where(mask)
(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2]))
```

but you need to do it in [Fortran order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26999092/3044825) (column by column) like so:

```
>>> np.where(mask, order='F') # not working, it doesn't support order parameter
(array([0, 1, 0, 2, 2]), array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2]))
```

It's not working but you could pass `mask.T` instead:

```
>>> np.where(mask.T) # fix
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 0, 2, 2]))
```

The remaining part is to split row indices into groups. In conclusion, you could solve your problem like so:

```
mask = A == np.amax(A, axis=0)
x, y = np.where(mask.T)
div_points = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(x)) + 1
np.split(y, div_points)
>>> [array([0, 1]), array([0, 2]), array([2])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function to get indices of max value in a column:

```
def idxMax(col):
    _, _, inv = np.unique(-col, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
    return np.where(inv == 0)[0].tolist()
```

Then generate the result as:

```
result = np.array([ idxMax(col) for col in A.T ], dtype=object)
```

For your source data, the result is:

```
array([list([0, 1]), list([0, 2]), list([2])], dtype=object)
```

Note that in general case there is no any guarantee that each column
will return the same number of max indices, so the result array is
a "ragged" one, and in this case *Numpy* requires *dtype=object* be passed.

But if it is enough for you to get a plain *pythonic* **list of lists**
(instead of a *Numpy* array), you can shrink the above code to:

```
result = [ idxMax(col) for col in A.T ]
```

In this case the result is:

```
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [2]]
```

Comment: The main drawback of `np.unique` here it not only finds all the indices of max value but also sorts all the column