# Fast Savgol Filter on 3D Tensor

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a tensor of example shape `(543, 133, 3)`, meaning 543 frames, with 133 points of X,Y,Z

I would like to run a `savgol_filter` on every point in every dimension, however, naively, this is quite slow:

```py
points, frames, dims = tensor.shape
new_data = []
for point in range(points):
  new_dims = []
  for dim in range(dims):
    new_dims.append(scipy.signal.savgol_filter(data[point, :, dim], 3, 1))
  new_data.append(new_dims)
tensor = np.array(new_data)
```

On my computer, for this small tensor, this takes 300ms, which is quite a long time.

Is there a way to make this faster?

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means the fastest method, but it should be quite a lot faster than what you're currently doing. We can utilize vectorized operations instead of `for` loops to achieve much better performance.

From your code, it seems like you want to smooth the `133` dimension (dim 1) and so you could apply SavGol all at once with
`savgol_filter(data, 3, 1, axis=1)`. In general you can specify the axis on which you'd like to apply the filter. On my computer, this brought the computation from 500ms to 2ms.

A side note: Since you care about performance, I would pay attention to what your data order is. Depending on what you're doing, it might be advisable to reorder your data once to save time.
For example: Let's say you have a matrix of 5 signals (5x299). If you wanted to get a single signal. That's easy! Try `signal[0]`. This doesn't actually require copying the data and we can just "view" it in memory. But what if you wanted to select a particular band in the signal? If you do `signal[:,0]` then you can't take a "view" of the memory because first you need to access every signal and take that index. If you had first transposed the matrix, then the first index is just the band of every spectra that you want -- no need for iteration. Data order can be an important part of getting the best performance out of your computations.

There are two related concepts here: contiguous memory and vectorized operations. My explanation of why data order is important has some more complications, and you will need to do your own research to determine what data ordering will give you the best performance for your application. The big things to watch out for are C v Fortran contiguous memory layout.

Here are some resources I found:     (not an endorsement)

StackOverflow article on contigous memory: [What is the difference between contiguous and non-contiguous arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998223/what-is-the-difference-between-contiguous-and-non-contiguous-arrays)

Towards Data Science article on vectorized operations https://towardsdatascience.com/vectorization-must-know-technique-to-speed-up-operations-100x-faster-50b6e89ddd45