# Expecting a contiguous tensor error with nn.Sum

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch

I have a 2x16x3x10x10 tensor that I feed into my network. My network has two parts that work in parallel. The first part takes the 16x3x10x10 matrix and computes the sum over the last two dimensions, returning a 16x3 tensor.
The second part is a convolutional neural network that produces a 16x160 tensor.
Whenever I try to run this model, I get the following error:

```
...903/nTorch/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/Tensor.lua:457: expecting a contiguous tensor
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'assert'
...903/nTorch/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/Tensor.lua:457: in function 'view'
...8/osu7903/nTorch/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sum.lua:26: in function 'updateGradInput'
...03/nTorch/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:40: in function 'updateGradInput'
...7903/nTorch/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Parallel.lua:52: in function 'updateGradInput'
...su7903/nTorch/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Module.lua:30: in function 'backward'
...03/nTorch/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:73: in function 'backward'
./train_v2_with_batch.lua:144: in function 'opfunc'
...su7903/nTorch/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/optim/sgd.lua:43: in function 'sgd'
./train_v2_with_batch.lua:160: in function 'train'
run.lua:93: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'dofile'
...rch/Torch7/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:131: in main chunk
[C]: at 0x00405800
```

Here is the relevant part of the model:

```
local first_part = nn.Parallel(1,2)
local CNN = nn.Sequential()

local sums = nn.Sequential()
sums:add(nn.Sum(3))
sums:add(nn.Sum(3))
first_part:add(sums)

-- stage 1: conv+max
CNN:add(nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(nfeats, convDepth_L1,receptiveFieldWidth_L1,receptiveFieldHeight_L1))  
-- Since the default stride of the receptive field is 1, then 
-- (assuming receptiveFieldWidth_L1 = receptiveFieldHeight_L1 = 3)  the number of receptive fields is (10-3+1)x(10-3+1) or 8x8
-- so the output volume is (convDepth_L1 X 8 X 8) or 10 x 8 x 8

--CNN:add(nn.Threshold())
CNN:add(nn.ReLU())
CNN:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(poolsize,poolsize,poolsize,poolsize)) 
-- if poolsize=2, then the output of this is 10x4x4

CNN:add(nn.Reshape(convDepth_L1*outputWdith_L2*outputWdith_L2,true))
first_part:add(CNN)
```

The code works when the input tensor is 2x1x3x10x10, but not when the tensor is 2x16x3x10x10.

Edit: I only just realized that this happens when I do model:backward and not model:forward. Here is the relevant code:

```
local y = model:forward(x)
local E = loss:forward(y,yt)

-- estimate df/dW
local dE_dy = loss:backward(y,yt)
print(dE_dy)
model:backward(x,dE_dy)
```

x is a 2x16x3x10x10 tensor and dE_dy is 16x2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a flaw in `torch.nn` library. To perform a backward step, `nn.Parallel` splits `gradOutput` it receives from higher module into pieces and sends them to its parallel submodules. Splitting are done effectively without copying memory, and thus those pieces are [non-contiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4059454) (unless you split on the 1st dimension).

```
local first_part = nn.Parallel(1,2)
--                               ^
--                 Merging on the 2nd dimension; 
--       Chunks of splitted gradOutput will not be contiguous
```

The problem is that `nn.Sum` cannot work with non-contiguous `gradOutput`. I haven't got a better idea than to make changes to it:

```
Sum_nc, _ = torch.class('nn.Sum_nc', 'nn.Sum')
function Sum_nc:updateGradInput(input, gradOutput)
    local size = input:size()
    size[self.dimension] = 1
    -- modified code:
    if gradOutput:isContiguous() then
        gradOutput = gradOutput:view(size) -- doesn't work with non-contiguous tensors
    else
        gradOutput = gradOutput:resize(size) -- slower because of memory reallocation and changes gradOutput
        -- gradOutput = gradOutput:clone():resize(size) -- doesn't change gradOutput; safer and even slower
    end
    --
    self.gradInput:resizeAs(input)
    self.gradInput:copy(gradOutput:expandAs(input))
    return self.gradInput
end 

[...]

sums = nn.Sequential()
sums:add(nn.Sum_nc(3)) -- <- will use torch.view
sums:add(nn.Sum_nc(3)) -- <- will use torch.resize
```

Comment: I have another question. Would it be possible to calculate the sum externally and pass it as a parameter to the network along with an image. Or is there a way for me to have two tensors of different sizes on different parts of the parallel network?