# Why I cannot use int arr[2][2] as a parameter?

Tags: c

```
void setArr(int x[2][2], int a, int b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            x[i][j] = 0;
}
int main(void)
{
    int *arr[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    }
    setArr(arr, 2, 2);
}
```

I know this code will not work, but I do not know the reason behind it. Can any one explain to my why, in this case, I cannot use x[2][2] as a parameter to receive arr.
Thanks

I put the code into a visualizer, and the setArr function sets the element of arr into NULL. I know that NULL is 0 in C. But I cannot connect why and how element of arr can be set to NULL.

Comment: it's a good read with this topic - hope it helps you - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-2d-array-parameter-c/

Comment: Because `int *arr[2];` declares ***an array of pointers*** while `void setArr(int x[2][2], ...)` expects a ***pointer to array of int [2]***. You want `void setArr(int **x, int a, int b)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No, they likely don't want `int**`, because they need a 2D array.

Comment: @Lundin - that is what the function is set up to take, but not what is declared in `main()`. One or the other has to change. Presuming the declaration in `main()` of `int *arr[2];` and the subsequent allocation is intended, then the parameter must change to `int **x`. If `main()` above is wrong and what was intended was `int arr[2][2];`, then the loop and allocation make no sense. How do you know which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can any one explain to my why, in this case, I cannot use x[2][2] as a parameter to receive arr.

Because you are using wildly different types. `int *arr[2];` is an array of 2 `int*`, each of them assigned to an allocated chunk of memory. That's a lookup table or "jagged array" if you will, not a proper 2D array. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for details.

Correct code for allocating a 2D array is this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void setArr(int a, int b, int x[a][b])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            x[i][j] = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int (*arr)[2] = malloc(sizeof(int[2][2])); 
    setArr(2, 2, arr);
    free(arr);
}
```

Here `arr` in main is a pointer to the first element of an `int[2][2]`. The first element of that 2D array is `int[2]`, and a pointer to such an element is `int(*)[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Function declaration `void setArr(int x[2][2], int a, int b)` declares `setArr` as a function that takes as a first parameter an array of 2 arrays each holding 2 integers. Whereas in the `main` you declare `arr` (the variable you pass to `setArr`) as `int *arr[2]`, that is as a pointer to an array of 2 integers.

The solution is to either change your code in `main`, for example by declaring `arr` as `int arr[2][2]` and remove the for loop, or change the `setArr` so that it takes a pointer to an array of two integers `void setArr(int *x[2], int a, int b)`.

I'm not sure if the latter could cause any problems (`gcc -Wall` compiles without warnings), but one thing to notice is the difference in memory layout when declaring `arr` as a pointer to an array of size 2 or declaring it as an array of 2 arrays of size 2. Compiling and executing the following should show you the difference:

```
    int main(void) {
        int *arr[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2); 
        }   
        printf("The address of arr[0] is %p\n", &arr[0]);
        printf("The address of arr[1] is %p\n\n", &arr[1]);
        printf("The address of arr[0][0] is %p\n", &arr[0][0]);
        printf("The address of arr[0][1] is %p\n", &arr[0][1]);
        printf("The address of arr[1][0] is %p\n", &arr[1][0]);
        printf("The address of arr[1][1] is %p\n\n", &arr[1][1]);

        int arr2[2][2]; 
        printf("The address of arr2[0] is %p\n", &arr2[0]);
        printf("The address of arr2[1] is %p\n\n", &arr2[1]);
        printf("The address of arr2[0][0] is %p\n", &arr2[0][0]);
        printf("The address of arr2[0][1] is %p\n", &arr2[0][1]);
        printf("The address of arr2[1][0] is %p\n", &arr2[1][0]);
        printf("The address of arr2[1][1] is %p\n", &arr2[1][1]);

        // setArr(arr, 2, 2); 
}
```

Running the executable once on my machine I got the following:

```
The address of arr[0] is 0x7ffe43d226b0
The address of arr[1] is 0x7ffe43d226b8

The address of arr[0][0] is 0xb62010
The address of arr[0][1] is 0xb62014
The address of arr[1][0] is 0xb62030
The address of arr[1][1] is 0xb62034

The address of arr2[0] is 0x7ffe43d226c0
The address of arr2[1] is 0x7ffe43d226c8

The address of arr2[0][0] is 0x7ffe43d226c0
The address of arr2[0][1] is 0x7ffe43d226c4
The address of arr2[1][0] is 0x7ffe43d226c8
The address of arr2[1][1] is 0x7ffe43d226cc
```

You can see that the when declaring `arr` as an pointer to an array, the two arrays of two integers are not [contiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059363/what-is-a-contiguous-memory-block), whereas when declaring it as an array of arrays, they are. Moreover, when declaring it as an array of arrays there is no need to dynamically allocate memory (e.g., using `malloc`).

Answer (score -1):

`x[2][2]` is just a declaration of a variable; there is no need to declare a var in input of a function; you must declare it before and just use its address:

```
void setArr(int** x, int a, int b)
```